# Why does float:left causes pre element to move down one line

Tags: html, css

In an HTML 5 document, I am trying to place two pre elements side by side using float:left like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pre and Float Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<pre style="float:left; margin-right:1em"> 1
 2
 3
 4</pre>
<pre>The quick
red fox
jumped over
the lazy brown dog.</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Internet Explorer 9 renders the HTML in the way I expected with the top of the left pre element aligned with the top of the other pre element, like this:

[image: An HTML document with two pre elements rendered in Internet Explorer 9]

However, both Google Chrome and Firefox render the document with the pre that is floated left about one line lower than the other pre, like this:

[image: An HTML document with two pre elements rendered in Google Chrome]

[image: An HTML document with two pre elements rendered in Firefox]

Given the history of Internet Explorer, I have to believe that Chrome and Firefox are correctly following the standard.  Even more interesting is that when I replace the pre elements with div elements and use `<br>` tags at the end of each line, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pre and Float Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:1em"> 1<br>
 2<br>
 3<br>
 4</div>
<div>The quick<br>
red fox<br>
jumped over<br>
the lazy brown dog.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the left div does not move down:

[image: An HTML document with two div elements rendered in Google Chrome]

Why does the standard require the left pre to move down? How can I stop Chrome and Firefox from moving the left pre down? I know how to work around it with CSS "position:relative; top:-1em", but this seems like a hack waiting to break. Is there a better way to stop Chrome and Firefox from moving the left pre down?

Comment: I don't have this issue on Firefox and Chrome. Can you please specify which version you're using ?

Comment: Also, why would you use `<pre>` for the layout of the page, while you should be using `<div>`, `<span>` etc.

Comment: Because I will put code in the pre element on the right, and pre honors the whitespace that I have in the code.

Comment: Did you look at [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) or are you deliberately reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I can't use JavaScript for this project, and CodeMirror is implemented in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the margin that `pre` may have by default on some browsers:

```css
pre {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre style="float:left; margin-right:1em"> 1
 2
 3
 4</pre>
<pre>The quick
red fox
jumped over
the lazy brown dog.</pre>
```

In this case, just removing `margin-top` would suffice.

Also consider using this CSS reset: `*{margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: It's a possible solution to the problem, but not an answer to the actual question about *why* it happens.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes My answer says the cause is that, on some browsers, `pre` elements have some margin by default.

Comment: Erm yeah thanks for editing that in after my comment. Also, the true cause of the difference is in collapsing margins as related to floating elements, not in the presence of the margins themselves. If it was just margins, both `<pre>` elements would still be at the same offset from the top.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I posted my answer at 20:56:21Z, and you posted your comment at 21:02:07Z. That's more than 5 minutes of difference, so if I edited my answer after you comment, you would see it in the edit history. And yes, your answer explains better the reasons, my answer focuses on solutions.

Comment: Yes, this answers the why for me.  Pre has a top margin.  This also answers how to "fix" it.  So simple.  A great answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does the standard require the left pre to move down?

It doesn't. The difference is simply in the 'user agent stylesheets'. Firefox and Chrome both use:

```
pre {
  margin:1em 0;
}
```

As the floating element is no longer part of the flow due to the floating itself, its top margin cannot collapse with the default margin on the body (8px in my Chrome here). The non-floating element however does, and its margin thus [correctly collapses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), rendering it a bit higher - the difference between 1em and 8px to be precise.

None of the referenced browsers are 'wrong', there are no strict rules for details like this in the user agent stylesheets - apart from the special meaningless elements `<div>` and `<span>`, which should by their very definition have no stylings, specifically margin or padding. As such the elements render as expected when replaced with divs.

IE9 isn't wrong, just different. Apparently it was changed in later versions to be more in line with the other main browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two elements side by side float is not needed. Given the size of the parent element you can set the width of both child elements to be less then the total of the parent element. Then set the child elements to `display:inline-block;` You will find the elements will be side by side in the correct order. Should the total width of the child elements be more then the width of the parent element then the child elements will be pushed to the next line. When calculating the width of an element you must add the border and the margin to the width of the element. When calculating the inside width of an element you must calculate the width minus the left and right padding.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pre and Float Test</title>
</head>
<style>
#elmOne{
margin-right:1em;
}
#elmOne, #elmTwo{
display:inline-block;
}
</style>

<body>
<pre id="elmOne"> 1
 2
 3
 4</pre>
<pre id="elmTwo">The quick
red fox
jumped over
the lazy brown dog.</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

There is very few times you will ever need to use float. Most of the time when you want to use float you can do it with position:[relative,fixed,absolute]; don't put your self in float hell.

If all you want is a list of items and have the items numbered then you don't need to have two elements side by side.  http://www.echoecho.com/htmllists02.htm

You can use:

```
<ol>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ol>
```

The `pre` tag is used to displayed in a fixed-width font, and it preserves both spaces and line breaks. Not used for lists but used for text layout. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp